# Is a power amplifier able to generate power? Does a power amplifier draw power from a supply?

Tags: power, power-amplifier

- Is a power amplifier able to generate power?
- Does a power amplifier draw power from a supply?
- Does a power amplifier dissipate power itself?
- If a power amplifier draws power from a supply, does it dissipate all of the indicated power drawn?

Answer (score 6):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1YNbt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The output stage of a power amplifier and the loudspeaker.*

> Is a power amplifier able to generate power?

No. The amplifier uses a power supply.<sup>1</sup>

> Does a power amplifier draw power from a supply?

Yes,  V1 and V2 in Figure 1.

- If Q1 is turned on current will flow from V1 through Q1 and into the speaker. This will push the speaker cone in one direction.
- If Q1 is turned off and Q2 is turned on current will flow from the speaker through Q2 and into V2.

> Does a power amplifier dissipate power itself?

Yes. The transistors behave a little like variable resistors. When the resistance decreases more current flows to the speaker. This current and the voltage across the transistor produces heat which has to be dissipated - usually on a heatsink at the back of the amplifier.<sup>2</sup>

> If a power amplifier draws power from a supply, does it dissipate all of the indicated power drawn?

No. ***Power in = Power out + heat***. Depending on the amplifier circuitry it could dissipate about half the power as heat and half to the speaker (which will also dissipate most of the power as heat).<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> This explanation uses a dual rail power supply for simplicity. Other arrangements are possible and common.

<sup>2</sup> To be more specific, \$ P_{Q} = V_{Q}I_{Q} \$ where \$ V_{Q} \$ is the voltage across the transistor.

<sup>3</sup> Higher efficiency amplifiers such as Class-D minimise power loss by switching at high frequency between V+ and V-. In this method a transistor is either fully off so \$ I = 0 \$ and \$ P_Q = 0 \$ or the transistor is fully on, the voltage across it is low and the resultant power dissipated in the transistor is low.

Answer (score 4):

> Is a power amplifier able to generate power?

No

> Does a power amplifier draw power from a supply?

Yes

> Does a power amplifier dissipate power itself?

Yes

> If a power amplifier draws power from a supply, does it dissipate all of the indicated power drawn?

Only if it's supplying no power to a load. If it supplies a load, then it dissipates the difference between what it draws from the supply, and what it supplies to the load.

Answer (score 3):

1. No, power comes from supply.
2. Yes, amplifier uses power from supply.
3. Yes, amplifier does consume power, there is no device that is 100% efficient.
4. No, an amplifier would usually take only the power it needs to provide some power at output.